# Weird issues with PointerWheelChanged

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a simple Page with a grid. The grid contains a TextBlock. I added a handler for PointerWheelChanged to the page.

For some reason, the event is only called when the mouse pointer is inside the TextBlock and not anywhere else.

I tried adding the event to the grid instead.

My code:

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="App.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    PointerWheelChanged="Page_PointerWheelChanged">

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="TextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="980" Width="1480" x:Name="test" FontSize="72"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

```cs
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;

namespace App {
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Page_PointerWheelChanged(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e) {
            var delta = e.GetCurrentPoint((UIElement)sender).Properties.MouseWheelDelta;
            test.Text = delta.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I originally found this in a more complex app. This is a simple app where I tried to reproduce this behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is different when you did not set a background for an Element and setting Background="Transparent" for an Element. The latter makes the controls interactive. You could try to give the grid a transparent background to allow the grid to respond to mouse events.

Like this:

```
  <Grid Background="Transparent" >
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="TextBlock" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="200" Width="200" x:Name="test" FontSize="72"/>
</Grid>
```

I changed the size of the Textblock a little bit due to the test purpose.